# Adding Multiple attachments for a DataGridView with Button Click

Tags: c#, datagridview, email-attachments

I wrote this code for adding multiple attachments to the datagridview with button click, but i m able to add only one attachment at a time. it wont add multiple attachments with the next button click, please provide a solution,

thanks

this is the code i tried

```
       OpenFileDialog ofdialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofdialog.Multiselect = true;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Attachments");

        var res = ofdialog.ShowDialog();


           string[] filename = ofdialog.FileNames;
           string[] sfilename =  ofdialog.SafeFileNames;

           foreach (string fn in filename)
           {
               dt.Rows.Add(fn);
           }


            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
            dataGridView1.Columns["Attachments"].Width = 500;
```

Comment: The code seems to be OK, can you place a breakpoint at the `foreach` line and look, if you get string.Count equal to number of selected files? Also, you can place breakpoint at the last line, hover your mouse cursor above `dt` where you're assigning the datasource on the previous line and use the "Zoom" icon to display the whole `DataTable` in "DataSet Visualizer".

Comment: hello thank you for the reply, i added a breakpoint to the last line and got the data from data visualizer, it shows only one row at a time, thats the problem i want to keep that row and another row. i can select multiple items and it works well, but i want to add items one by one.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breakpoint at the last line (from comment): Well, of course this doesn't resolve the issue, but now you know the `DataTable` itself is wrong. Now *proceed upwards* your code with the breakpoint. You can set it on the `DataTable dt = new DataTable();` line and look into the line above, when hovering above the `ofdialog`, look into it's collections of files in `FileNames`.

[image]

With `OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = True` you should get number of files equal to what you selected in the `OpenFileDialog`.

Next candidate is the `filename` array with breakpoint on `foreach`, checking number of items in this array.

Here is code I am using for comparison:

C# (converted):

```
OpenFileDialogDXF.Title = "Choose your files";
OpenFileDialogDXF.InitialDirectory = @"C:\users\XXXXX\Documents\";
OpenFileDialogDXF.Filter = "DXF Files|*.dxf";
OpenFileDialogDXF.Multiselect = true;

if (OpenFileDialogDXF.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    for (var ir = 0; ir <= OpenFileDialogDXF.FileNames.Count - 1; ir++)
        LoadDXF(OpenFileDialogDXF.FileNames(ir));
}
```

VB.NET:

```
Private Sub BtnOpenDxf_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnOpenDxf.Click
    OpenFileDialogDXF.Title = "Choose your files"
    OpenFileDialogDXF.InitialDirectory = "C:\users\XXXXX\Documents\"
    OpenFileDialogDXF.Filter = "DXF Files|*.dxf"
    OpenFileDialogDXF.Multiselect = True

    If OpenFileDialogDXF.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        For ir = 0 To OpenFileDialogDXF.FileNames.Count - 1
            Call LoadDXF(OpenFileDialogDXF.FileNames(ir))
        Next
    End If
```

Where `LoadDXF` is a my custom sub which handles each file.

**EDIT:**

Thinking about your code, if the `OpenFileDialog` gets multiple results, the place I'd look for a problem is this line:

```
string[] filename = ofdialog.FileNames;
```

It might need some conversion like `.ToArray()`.